# No RT or DLSS with 4070 and driver 530.x

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, games

So i gave up Windows because i like what Steam did for gaming on Linux and i always wanted to switch to Linux anyway. I got everything set up for my daily use EXCEPT of RT and DLSS.

No matter what i do, it wont turn on. It stays greyed out.

My GF just got her first gaming PC and has the same problem.
She is on a rtx 3070Ti and does not have DLSS or RT in Cyberpunk (Steam) or DLSS in Jurassic World Evolution 2.

I tried so much stuff i found on the internet but nothing worked so far.

I tried Steam, Lutris and Heroic Games Launcher. Non worked.

I am on driver version 530.41.03 installed with apt-get on Kubuntu.

Specs:

- RTX 4070 FE
- Ryzen 5 3600
- 16GB RAM
- Kubuntu 23.04 on KDE Plasma 5.27.4
- Kernel 6.2.0-20-gemeric (64-bit)

I tried Cyberpunk and Metro Exodus over Heroic and Lutris (GOG Versions).
Cyberpunk no DLSS and no RT and Metro Crashes after Intro.

On Steam i tried HITMAN 3 where the game works fine but also greyed out RT and if you turn on DLSS you have a white Screen with purple glitches. Very weird.

Portal with Raytracing works, but the Performance is meh.

I tried every game with different Proton Versions (7, 8, Experimental and GE).

I tried every game with and without these Arguments:

```
PROTON_ENABLE_NVAPI=1 PROTON_HIDE_NVIDIA_GPU=0 VKD3D_CONFIG=dxr11 %command%
```

Maybe helpful: I found something weird in the Cyberpunk log from Heroic:

```
OS: Freedesktop SDK KERNEL: 6.2.0-20-generic ARCH: x64
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor u/3.6 GOVERNOR: schedutil
RAM: Total: 15.51 GiB Available: 11.28 GiB
GRAPHICS: GPU0: Device 2786 VRAM: 32MB PROTOCOL: x11
```

Seems like it does not detect my GPU

Some Infos from bash:

```
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation AD104 [GeForce RTX 4070] (rev a1)
Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 17ff
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I hope anyone has some Ideas i can test.
Would even start from scratch if that means i could play games the way i want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are having issues with Steam? Have you gone to the Steam support site and see what it says about the games you are trying to run?

Comment: It is not just Steam, it happens with Heroic Games Launcher and Lutris too.
I looked into several Steam sources but none of the fixes seem to help.

Comment: All of which are not Ubuntu but environments you are running on top of Ubuntu. Each have there own support.

Comment: I was hoping, since no one else was able to help, that maybe the people here are. It could be a problem with missing packages i need to install, alltough i didnt find any missing. If this is the wrong space to ask this kind of questions, i am sorry.

Comment: No need for sorry it simply not a Ubuntu problem. I also just noticed you are using 23.04 and it is having a TON of issues. Maybe use Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The 23.04 is only supported for 9 months from release date.

Comment: Uh, didnt know about that. That means i would have to start from Scratch right?
Just finished setting everything up for daily use.

Comment: Yes you would have to do a complete new install.

Comment: Thank you David